# Share / view files betweek Mac OS X and Linux (Ubuntu) using sshfs and GUI

Tags: network, unix, ssh, file-sharing

I just want to access file from Mac OS X (Big Sur / 11.2.1) on my Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.2 machine) and vice versa.

I did not like the idea using SMB - or should I really do it??

**What I did**

1. OS X : Enabled System Preferences -> Sharing -> Remote Login
2. OS X: I am able to type sshfs
    (not sure why it knows the command I did some other experiments the other days (e.g. installed meld via brew)
3. Linux enabled ssh (server)

**What works good**

1. Access OS X Filesystem from Ubuntu via `sshfs user@192.168.0.1`
2. Access OS X Filesystem from Ubuntu via the `files` application by typing `sftp://192.168.0.1`

**What works not-so-good**

Access the Linux / Ubuntu filesystem from Mac OS X : 
`sshfs user@192.168.0.2:/ localMountDir` works as well BUT:

1. **strange user and group : user: root, group weel**
2. going deeper into the path (which is internally another SSD the **permission** changes from **755 to 750** (or rwxr-xr-x to rwxr-x---)

**How to fix the issue ??**

- I would guess it has to do with this trange user/group root/weel
- If so how to fix this ?? I looked a little bit about users and groups in OS X but on the GUI -> System Preferences -> Users and Groups -> I do not see any groups

Comment: Might be helpful, if you could edit your question and include the version of OS X and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your command to mount your Linux drive on Mac,

```
sshfs user@192.168.0.2:/ localMountDir
```

it looks like you are specifying that you want to mount the root of the Linux filesystem (that’s the `:/` part). In general, most operating systems assign ownership of root-level directories to a privileged user (i.e., not you). In the case of Linux, `root` is the name of the superuser and `wheel` is the name of the group to which `root` belongs. So what you are seeing is, in fact, **100% correct**. And it’s also no surprise that permissions become more restrictive as you descend into certain directories (e.g., if you are trying to `cd` into your own home directory then it’s **expected** that it is not world-readable [75***0***], whereas the root of the filesystem *should* be world-readable [75***5***].)

What I suspect you’re wanting to do is to `sshfs` directly into your own home directory on the Linux box. So you’d want to specify that on your command line:

```
sshfs user@192.168.0.2:/home/YOURUSERNAME localMountDir
```

Comment: Indeed one of the folders did have permissions 750 which was ok local because my user is in the group. But with sshfs (root:weel) I am not in the group on the mac